# PHP, Echo only one time in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

i'have an array, and then i have a script who gets the category i'm browsing (using wordpress) and put it in the $category variable.

So i test if the category i'm browsing it's equal to the $array key and then i paste some text

```
$array = array ('key' => 'value', ... )

//...
// a script who gets the category i'm browsing and store it in the $category variable    
//...
/* starting the foreach loop */
foreach( $array as $key => $value) {
            if ($category == $key) {
                echo "some $value here";    
            } elseif ($category !== $key) {
                echo "nothing"; 
            }
```

The problem is that this loop does **echo "nothing"** for each time the $category is not equal to the $key for each element of the array.

So if i have 20 key => value in the array this loop paste one time "some $value here" and 19 times "nothing"

there is a way to echo "nothing" only one time?

Thank you!

Comment: Use a flag,set it to zero in start and increment it in foreach loop if it is equal to zero then show nothing

Comment: this is why we use counters in loop.

Comment: Why you want to print nothing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) instead of the `foreach` loop:

```
if (array_key_exists($category, $array)) {
    echo $array[$category];
} else {
    echo 'nothing';
}
```

Comment: This is the simplest. :) .. but if all the values needed to be printed then it will not work.

Comment: @sgt I modified to example. It's an associative array, so only one key can be equal with `$category`. And then it's easy to print the value.

Comment: either way the loop is required. :)

Comment: @sgt Why is it required?

Comment: `$category` is the `key` right? then how can you check them one by one?

Comment: @sgt There is no need for that, `array_key_exists` already checks that. There can only be one key which equals with `$category`.

Comment: and what for multiple keys?

Comment: @sgt An associative array can't have two keys with equivalent names.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it's works fine but not for my purpose

Answer (score 0):

```
    $i=0;
    foreach( $array as $key => $value) {
$i++;
                if ($category == $key) {
                    echo "some $value here";    
                } elseif($category !== $key)
                {
                  if($i<=1)
    {
                    echo "nothing"; 
    }
    else{}
                }
```

Comment: If condition should be out of loop

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$i = 1;
foreach( $array as $key => $value) {
            if ($category == $key) {
                echo "some $value here";    
            } elseif ($category !== $key) {
                $i++; 
            }
}
if (count($array) == $i) {
    echo "nothing";
}
```